# How to do inner join in Vertica Update?

Tags: sql, vertica

I was trying to do a inner join with 3 tables in a update query. I tried to find the solution in multiple sites but didn't get the solution. 
Following a sample query I am trying:

```
UPDATE TGT
SET C1 = CASE WHEN TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'P' THEN SRC.C1 ELSE NULL END,
C2 = CASE WHEN TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'D' THEN SRC.C1 ELSE NULL END
FROM SRC
INNER JOIN SRC1
ON SRC.C9 = SRC1.C9
AND SRC.C9 = TGT.C9;
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: You are updating TGT records with values from SRC/SRC1. So there is exactly one record in SRC/SRC1 per C9? And why do you even join SRC1;? I don't see it used anywhere in your query.

Comment: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "on"

Comment: And as mentioned in my answer to your previous question: It seems you are making very simple things very complicated. Don't try to perform different updates in a complex single statement when you can do the same with extremely simple separate statements (in one single transaction probably).

Comment: Actually I have to update 7 columns in a table. Which will give good performance ... 7 different queries or 1 single update query??

Comment: In your case: 7 different queries I would say.

Comment: If they're all wrapped within a single transaction, the performance difference will probably be next to nothing.  Sometimes it's better to sacrifice potential slight performance gains in the name of maintainability.

Comment: Your update syntax, even without the join, is still queer. How many SRC records with the same c2 and c9 can exist? How many SRC records with the same c2 and c9 and c3 can exist? How many SRC1 records with the same c9 can exist?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect your syntax to work.  (I don't have Vertica handy but its query parser is based on Postgres.)

Perhaps -- unlike Postgres -- `JOIN` is not allowed in the `FROM`.  Then you can put the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE TGT
    SET C1 = (CASE WHEN TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'P' THEN SRC.C1 END)
        C2 = (CASE WHEN TGT.c2 = SRC.c2 AND SRC.C3 = 'D' THEN SRC.C1 END)
FROM SRC, SRC1
WHERE SRC.C9 = SRC1.C9 AND SRC.C9 = TGT.C9;
```